# pandas read csv with quotes at beginning and ending of every tow

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parsing, data-cleaning

I have a csv file with a that is encoded with commas as separator but every row has a quote character at the start and at the end of each row.

In practice the data look like this

```
"0.00000E+000,6.25000E-001"
"1.00000E+000,1.11926E+000"
"2.00000E+000,9.01726E-001"
"3.00000E+000,7.71311E-001"
"4.00000E+000,6.82476E-001"
```

If I read the data using pd.read_csv() it just reads everything under a single column. What is the best workaround? Is there a simple way to pre-emptively strip the quotes character from the whole csv file?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a short, representative sample of the contents of the file?

Comment: The purpose of double quotes in a CSV is to allow a comma to be a valid character inside a string, like if you have `Miami, FL` in a `Location` column. Stripping them all would be a risky move.

Answer (score 0):

If your file looks like

```
my_file=""""0.00000E+000,6.25000E-001"
"1.00000E+000,1.11926E+000"
"2.00000E+000,9.01726E-001"
"3.00000E+000,7.71311E-001"
"4.00000E+000,6.82476E-001"
"""
```

One way to remove the quotes prior to using Pandas would be

```
for line in my_file.split('\n'):
    print(line.replace('"',''))
```

To write that to file, use

```
with open('output.csv','w') as file_handle:
    for line in my_file.split('\n'):
        file_handle.write(line.replace('"','')+'\n')
```